# How to specify several variables in the map directive of nginx

Tags: nginx, configuration

Well I have [a slightly different question than this one](https://serverfault.com/questions/609042/nginx-map-directive-for-multiple-variables): I don't want to map two variables at the same time, I want to map one variable using two others as parameters.

Indeed I have read [in the documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html#map) about the map directive that:

> Before version 0.9.0 only a single variable could be specified in the
>   first parameter.

So, as I have nginx 1.8, I expect to be able to use more than a single variable in the first parameter.

This led me to think that I could write something like the two last map directives in this example:

```
map $http_user_agent $bot {
    default         "";
    "~*Googlebot"   "yes";
    "~*MJ12bot"     "yes";
    "~*bingbot"     "yes";
    etc.
}

map $request        $bot    $np {
    default         ""      "";
    default         "yes"   "";
    "~*newproject"  ""      "yes";
    "~*newproject"  "yes"   "";
}

map $bot    $np     $regular {
    ""      ""      "yes";
    ""      "yes"   "";
    "yes"   ""      "";
}
```

But it doesn't work (`nginx -t` returns a

> invalid number of arguments in "map" directive

)

So, how is it possible to specify several variables in the first parameter? Or, what does actually mean the documentation, if I misunderstood it?

Comment: I've added an answer to the question, but actually this question looks like an XY-problem http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: Maybe it's kind of (and I didn't know about them). But I was truly thinking it's actually not possible and there's something I miss to understand in the documentation. It's clear now.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You have misunderstood nginx's docs. It means that before version 0.9 first argument of the `map` must be single variable and nothing else. Since version 0.9.0 first argument could be any string with any number of variables to interpolate.

Here how your first block could look like:

```
map "$bot:$request"      $np {
    default              "";
    "~^yes:"             "";
    "~*^:.*newproject"   "yes";
}
```